# Is it possible to mount a remote storage to local file system of iOS?

Tags: ios, vfs

Is it possible to implement a VFS driver on iOS, which can mount a remote storage like dropbox to local file system? I don't think it is allowed for a normal iOS devices, but how about jailbreak devices?

Answer (score 0):

There is [Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/ios) for iOS that allow listing and using Dropbox storage: . Classic unix mounting is forbidden.